# rotate a texture2d till 540 degrees with touchmove

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a texture 2d on my gui screen. I want to rotate this texture till +540 and -540 degrees with finger touch rotate. Beyond this limit it should stop rotating.
can any1 help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Texture2D steering;
    public static TouchControl Instance;
    public float angleRotate=0f;
    public float carRotation=0f;
    public int finger;


    private Matrix4x4 savedMatrix;  
    private float steerAngleRad;
    public float steerAngleDeg;
    private float steerAngleRadTemp;
    public float steerAngleDegTemp;
    private float dx=0f;
    private float dy=0f;
    private int i;
    private float newAngle =0f;
    private float initAngle;
    private float rotationLimit=540f;
    public float secondWheelRot=0f;
    private float preRotDeg=0f;
    private float angleDiff=0f;
    private bool clockWheel=false;
    private bool onlyOnce=false;

    private Vector2 steeringPos;
    private Vector2 centre;
    private bool inXRange=false;
    private bool inYRange=false;
//  private bool moving=false;
    private float steeringWidth=0f;
    private float steeringHeight=0f;

    private float gobackSpeed=20f;

    void Start()
    {
        Instance=this;
        i=0;
        finger=3;
        steeringPos=new Vector2(Screen.width*0.025f,Screen.height*0.68f);
        steeringWidth=Screen.width*0.12f;
        steeringHeight=steeringWidth;
        centre = new Vector2(steeringPos.x + steeringWidth / 2, steeringPos.y + steeringHeight / 2);
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if(Input.touchCount>0 && (!PauseButton.pauseFlag && !DamageBar.Instance.levelLost && !GameTimer.Instance.levelLost && !CommonIndicator.Instance.levelComplete))
        {   
            for(i=0;i< Input.touchCount; ++i)
            {
                if(Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > 0f && Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < steeringWidth+Screen.width*0.1f)
                {
                    inXRange=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    inXRange=false;
                }
                if(Input.GetTouch(i).position.y > 0f && Input.GetTouch(i).position.y < Screen.height-(steeringPos.y))
                {
                    inYRange=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    inYRange=false;
                }

                ///////////////if touch is in the range/////////////////////
                if(inXRange && inYRange)
                {
                    if(Input.GetTouch(i).phase==TouchPhase.Began)
                    {
                        finger=Input.touches[i].fingerId;
                        dx=Input.GetTouch(i).position.x-centre.x;
                        dy=Input.GetTouch(i).position.y-(Screen.height-centre.y);
                        steerAngleRadTemp=Mathf.Atan2(dy,dx);
                        steerAngleDegTemp=-steerAngleRadTemp*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                    }
                    if((Input.GetTouch(i).phase==TouchPhase.Stationary || Input.GetTouch(i).phase==TouchPhase.Moved))
                    {
                        preRotDeg=newAngle;
                        if(preRotDeg<-180f && preRotDeg>-360f)
                        {
                            preRotDeg+=360f;
                        }
                        if(preRotDeg>180f && preRotDeg<360f)
                        {
                            preRotDeg-=360f;
                        }
                        dx=Input.GetTouch(i).position.x-centre.x;
                        dy=Input.GetTouch(i).position.y-(Screen.height-centre.y);
                        steerAngleRad=Mathf.Atan2(dy,dx);
                        steerAngleDeg=-steerAngleRad*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                        angleRotate=steerAngleDeg-steerAngleDegTemp;
                        newAngle=angleRotate;
                        if(newAngle<-180f && newAngle>-360f)
                        {
                            newAngle+=360f;
                        }
                        if(newAngle>180f && newAngle<360f)
                        {
                            newAngle-=360f;
                        }
                        if(!onlyOnce)
                        {
                            onlyOnce=true;
                            if(newAngle>preRotDeg)
                                clockWheel=true;
                            else
                                clockWheel=false;
                        }
                        if(clockWheel && preRotDeg>0f && newAngle < 0f)
                        {
                            clockWheel=true;
                        }
                        else if(clockWheel && preRotDeg<0f && newAngle >0f)
                        {
                            clockWheel=true;
                        }
                        else if(!clockWheel && preRotDeg>0f && newAngle <0f)
                        {
                            clockWheel=false;
                        }
                        else if(!clockWheel && preRotDeg<0f && newAngle >0f)
                        {
                            clockWheel=false;
                        }
                        else if(newAngle>preRotDeg)
                        {
                            clockWheel=true;
                        }
                        else if(newAngle<preRotDeg)
                        {
                            clockWheel=false;
                        }
                        if(Mathf.Abs(newAngle)>Mathf.Abs(preRotDeg))
                        {
                            angleDiff=Mathf.Abs(newAngle)-Mathf.Abs(preRotDeg);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            angleDiff=Mathf.Abs(preRotDeg)-Mathf.Abs(newAngle);
                        }
                        if(clockWheel)
                        {
                            carRotation+=angleDiff;
                            secondWheelRot+=angleDiff;
                            if(secondWheelRot>rotationLimit)
                            {
                                secondWheelRot=rotationLimit;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            carRotation-=angleDiff;
                            secondWheelRot-=angleDiff;
                            if(secondWheelRot<-rotationLimit)
                            {
                                secondWheelRot=-rotationLimit;
                            }   
                        }
                    }
//                  else
//                  {
//                      steeringToZero();                       
//                  }
                    if(Input.GetTouch(i).phase==TouchPhase.Ended)// && Input.touches[i].fingerId != AccControl.Instance.finger)
                    {
                        onlyOnce=false;
                        carRotation=0f;
                        angleRotate=0f;
                        newAngle=0f;
                        steeringToZero();
                        finger=3;
                    }
                }
                else if(!AccControl.Instance.onPadTouch && finger==3)
                {
                    steeringToZero();                       
                }
            }
        }
        else if(Input.touchCount==0)
        {
            steeringToZero();
        }
        if(Input.touchCount==1 && AccControl.Instance.onPadTouch)
        {
            steeringToZero();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && !PauseButton.pauseFlag) 
        { 
            Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
        }
    }
    void steeringToZero()
    {
        if(secondWheelRot>0)
        {
            secondWheelRot-=gobackSpeed/(Input.touchCount+1);
        }
        else if(secondWheelRot<0)
        {
            secondWheelRot+=gobackSpeed/(Input.touchCount+1);
        }
        if(secondWheelRot<gobackSpeed && secondWheelRot>-gobackSpeed)
        {
            secondWheelRot=0f;
        }

    }

    void OnGUI() 
    {
        savedMatrix = GUI.matrix;
        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(carRotation,centre);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(steeringPos.x,steeringPos.y, steeringWidth, steeringHeight), steering);
        GUI.matrix = savedMatrix;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can't rotate GUI texture. I suppose the best way to do what you want is to assign a plane as a child to camera facing it, and rotate that plane as you want.